# GCS API Error on /surveys/{surveyUrlId}/results for surveys without responses

Tags: google-surveys

We are testing our programmatic surveying deployment processes.

Recently, we noticed that those surveys that were manually stopped (status completed) that didn't gather any responses, seem to return a 503 error.

`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 503 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/consumersurveys/v2/surveys/shlxjagoe2asdks4ldtmon22km/results?alt=media returned "Service Unavailable">`

Is this the expected response? Perhaps this is causing some error on your end?

This does not seem to be documented at https://developers.google.com/consumer-surveys/v2/reference/results/get

Now regarding the survey resource state, there seems to be a 'paused' state. There is also a 'stop' method which actually marks it as 'complete'. So the question is, can we actually pause a running survey? or that's not available yet?. This is not explained in the documentation either.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a survey is stopped without responses, it will not have a results file.

We don't allow users to Pause a survey. A survey can be paused by our Ops processes and it can be put into the Paused state when targeting a custom audience that requires "incidence based pricing". 
https://support.google.com/consumersurveys/answer/2447244?rd=1

We're working on updating the documentation and response messages to make this clearer and providing a guide to users to explain the incidence based pricing flows in the API.